# Derivative of the "surface potential energy" functional

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed manifold and $\omega$ a closed $2$-form on $M$ such that
$$
   \int_{S^2} f^* \omega \in \mathbb Z
$$
for any smooth $f \colon S^2 \to M$. For a given $x \in \mathcal LM = C^\infty(\mathbb R / \mathbb Z,M)$, assuming contractibility, we set
$$
  L(x) = \int_{B^2} u^*\omega \quad \in \mathbb R / \mathbb Z,
$$
where $B^2 = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid |z| \leq 1\}$ and $u \colon B^2 \to M$ is a smooth map such that $u(e^{2\pi i t}) = x(t)$. I want to show that
$$
  dL(x)\xi = \int_0^1 \omega(\xi(t),\dot x(t)),
$$
for any $\xi \in C^\infty(x^* TM) = T_x \mathcal LM$.

I tried to do this by definition: I take a family of closed loops $x_s(t)$ such that $x_0(t) = x(t)$ and also $\partial_s x_s(t)|_{s=0} = \xi(t)$. Then I continue $\xi$ to some vector field aroung $u(B^2)$ and consider its flow $\phi_s$. Then I compute
$$
   \partial_s L(x_s(t))|_{s=0} = \int_{B^2} \partial_s (\phi_s u)^*\omega |_{s=0} = \int_{B^2} \partial_s u^* \phi_s^*\omega |_{s=0} \\ 
 \int_{B^2} du^* \circ \partial_s \phi^*_s \omega |_{s=0} = \int_{B^2}du^* \circ \mathcal L_\xi \omega ,
$$
taking into account that $u_s = \phi_s u \colon B^2 \to M$, $u_s(e^{2\pi i t}) = x_s(t)$, and the definition of the Lie derivative. However, I don't see how to procced. Could you help me please?

Comment: I haven't read the whole calculation, but it seems you want to arrive at the contraction of $\omega$ with $\xi$. Why don't you use Cartan's magic formula on the last equality?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo nice, it solves the problem!